# probability of drawing a 5 card flush given n cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $n$ random cards from a standard $52$ card deck, what is the probability of getting at least a 5 card flush within those $n$ cards? $n$ would be 5 <= $n$ < 17. The probability would get closer and closer to 1 as $n$ approaches 17. Basically, I need an equation to compute the increasing probability of getting at least a 5 card flush as you draw more and more cards from a 52 card deck.

Is it simply $$\frac {(^4C_1*   ^{13}C_5)}{^{52}C_n}$$

Comment: The question is not clear. What is $n\geqslant 5$, the number of cards you draw from the 52-card deck? Then what do you mean by flush on $n$ cards?

Comment: You draw n random cards from the 52-card deck. The question is what is the probability that there is a flush (5 cards with the same suit) within those n cards? eg. n=10 If I draw 10 cards from a 52 card deck, what is the probability that at least 5 of those cards will have the same suit (flush).

Comment: For n > 16, the probability should = 1.  That exprssion doesn't look right.

Comment: I am aware that n > 16 would equal probability 1. I am trying to find a way to compute the increasing probability of drawing a flush as n goes from 5 to 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the formulas a little more compact, I'm going to use the notation $\binom pq$ rather than $^pC_q$ for number of combinations.

Notice that $^4C_1 \times {^{13}C_5} = \binom41\binom{13}{5}$ is a constant, whereas $^{52}C_n = \binom{52}{n}$ increases as $n$ increases, so
$$
\frac{\binom41\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{n}}
$$
gets progressively *smaller* as $n$ gets larger, opposite from what you know the correct answer must do. Therefore this cannot be the answer.

The formula above is correct in the case $n=5$ only.
It is true that the probability of drawing at least one $5$-card flush in $n$
cards can be expressed as a fraction with denominator $\binom{52}{n},$
but in general the numerator is larger than $\binom41\binom{13}{5}.$

Let $K(n)$ be the number of $n$-card hands with at least one $5$-card flush, so that the desired probability is
$$
\frac{K(n)}{\binom{52}{n}},
$$
and let's see how we can compute $K(n)$ for a few different values of $n.$

For $n=6,$ we have to consider the $\binom{13}{6}$ different sets of $6$ cards that might be drawn from one suit times the $4$ different suits from which they might be drawn; but we also have to consider the $\binom{13}{5}$ different sets of $5$ cards that might be drawn from one suit times the $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to draw the sixth card from another suite times the $4\times3$ different permutations of suits from which they might be drawn.
So
$$
K(6) = 4 \binom{13}{6} + 12 \binom{13}{5} \binom{13}{1} = 207636.
$$

For $n=7$ the possibilities are not just $7$ of one suit or $6$ of one suit and $1$ of another; it could be $5$ of one suit and $2$ of another, or $5$ of one suit and $1$ each of two others. In that last case, the only choices of suits are $4$ choices for the long suit and which of the other $3$ suits does *not* occur; it doesn't matter which of the two singleton suits we write first. So
$$
K(7) = 4 \binom{13}{7} + 12 \binom{13}{6} \binom{13}{1}
 + 12 \binom{13}{5} \binom{13}{2} + 12 \binom{13}{5} \binom{13}{1}^2
= 4089228
$$

It's hard to imagine how we're going to write a simple formula for $K(n)$ using the usual combinatoric functions, since for the next few $n,$ each time we add a card we increase the number of different possible counts of cards by suit; for example, for $n=8$ the number of cards in each suit can be $8$ (all one suit), $7 + 1,$ $6+2,$ $6+1+1,$ $5+3,$ $5+2+1,$ or $5+1+1.$
The formula would not even fit on one line of this answer format.

For $n$ close to $17,$ the formulas are simpler
if we count the number of non-flushes, that is,
$\binom{52}{n} - K(n).$
For example, for $n=16,$ the only non-flushes obtained by drawing $4$ cards from each suit,
$$
\binom{52}{16} - K(16) = \binom{13}{4}^4 = 261351000625.
$$
For $n=15,$ we can only have $4$ cards from three of the suits and $3$ from the other, with $4$ different choices of the $3$-card suit, so
$$
\binom{52}{15} - K(15) = 4 \binom{13}{4}^3 \binom{13}{3} = 418161601000.
$$

For $n=14,$ the possible numbers of cards of each suit are $4+4+4+2$ or
$4+4+3+3$, so
$$
\binom{52}{14} - K(14)
 = 4 \binom{13}{4}^3 \binom{13}{2} + \binom62 \binom{13}{4}^2 \binom{13}{3}^2
 = 364941033600.
$$

Observing that $\binom{52}{6} - K(6) = 20150884$
and $\binom{52}{7} - K(7) = 129695332,$
we can see that the result of the computer calculation
[offered in another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2622642)
is correct for $n \in \{4,5,6,7,14,15, 16, 17\}.$

Answer (score 0):

I've got kind of a dumb answer. I just wrote a program that counts the number $f$ of non-flush hands for a hand of $n$ cards and the total number of possible hands $t$ to arrive at the probability $P=1-f/t$.

```
! flush.f90 -- Calculates probability of getting a flush
module FlushFun
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer choose(0:13)
   contains
      function nfree(n)
         integer n
         integer(INT64) nfree
         integer n1, n2, n3
         integer(INT64) L1, L2, L3
         nfree = 0
         do n1 = max(0,n-12), min(4,n)
            L1 = choose(n1)
            do n2 = max(0,n-n1-8), min(4,n-n1)
               L2 = L1*choose(n2)
               do n3 = max(0,n-n1-n2-4), min(4,n-n1-n2)
                  L3 = L2*choose(n3)
                  nfree = nfree+L3*choose(n-n1-n2-n3)
               end do
            end do
         end do
      end function nfree
      function ntotal(n)
         integer n
         integer(INT64) ntotal
         integer i
         ntotal = 1
         do i = 1, N
            ntotal = ntotal*(52-i+1)/i
         end do
      end function ntotal
      subroutine init_params
         integer i
         integer(INT64) j
         integer(INT64) fact(0:13)
         fact = [(product([(j,j=1,i)]),i=0,13)]
         choose = [(fact(13)/fact(i)/fact(13-i),i=0,13)]
      end subroutine init_params
end module FlushFun

program flush
   use FlushFun
   implicit none
   integer(INT64) free, total
   real(REAL64) probability
   integer n
   call init_params
   write(*,'(a)') '\begin{array}{rrrl}'
   write(*,'(a)') '\text{Cards} & \text{Non-Flush} & \text{Total} & \text{Probability}\\'
   write(*,'(a)') '\hline'
   do n = 4,17
      free = nfree(n)
      total = ntotal(n)
      probability = 1-real(free,REAL64)/total
      write(*,'(*(g0))') n, ' & ', free,' & ',total,' & ',probability,' \\'
   end do
   write(*,'(a)') '\end{array}'
end program flush
```

$$\begin{array}{rrrl}
\text{Cards} & \text{Non-Flush} & \text{Total} & \text{Probability}\\
\hline
4 & 270725 & 270725 & 0.0000000000000000 \\
5 & 2593812 & 2598960 & 0.19807923169267161E-002 \\
6 & 20150884 & 20358520 & 0.10198973206303807E-001 \\
7 & 129695332 & 133784560 & 0.30565769323455561E-001 \\
8 & 700131510 & 752538150 & 0.69639844837102283E-001 \\
9 & 3187627300 & 3679075400 & 0.13357924113216058 \\
10 & 12234737086 & 15820024220 & 0.22662968679070705 \\
11 & 39326862432 & 60403728840 & 0.34893320019744667 \\
12 & 104364416156 & 206379406870 & 0.49430799449026441 \\
13 & 222766089260 & 635013559600 & 0.64919475199817445 \\
14 & 364941033600 & 1768966344600 & 0.79369814767023128 \\
15 & 418161601000 & 4481381406320 & 0.90668912929163414 \\
16 & 261351000625 & 10363194502115 & 0.97478084575449575 \\
17 & 0 & 21945588357420 & 1.0000000000000000 \\
\end{array}$$
Not carefully checked, but at least it gives the right answers for $n\in\{4,5,17\}$.

**EDIT**: To show how you could solve this problem by hand I wrote a program that really does find all the partitions of $n$ into $4$ integers in $[0,4]$. The most partitions you get is $8$ for $n=8$. Consider the partition $8=4+2+2+0$. In the table below this is represented as $4$ clubs, $2$ diamonds, $2$ hearts and no spades, but there are actually
$$\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}=12$$
Ways to choose the suits. For the given choice of suits, there are $\binom{13}{4}=715$ ways to select $4$ clubs, $\binom{13}{2}=78$ ways to select $2$ diamonds,  $\binom{13}{2}=78$ ways to select $2$ hearts, and $\binom{13}{0}=1$ way to select $0$ spades, so there are $12\times715\times78\times78\times1=52200720$ possible non-flush hands with the $4-2-2-0$ distribution. Here is the program that shows these calculations:

```
! flush2.f90 -- Calculates probability of getting a flush
module FlushFun
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
   implicit none
   integer choose(0:13)
   contains
      function nfree(n)
         integer n
         integer(INT64) nfree
         integer n1, n2, n3, n4
         integer(INT64) L1, L2, L3, L4
         integer(INT64) term
         integer current, w1, w2, w3, w4
         nfree = 0
         write(*,'(a)') '$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}'
         write(*,'(a)') '\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&'// &
            '&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\'
         write(*,'(a)') '\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&'// &
            '\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&'// &
            '\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\'
         write(*,'(a)') '\hline'
         do n1 = min(4,n), (n+3)/4, -1
            L1 = choose(n1)
            w1 = 1
            current = 1
            do n2 = min(n1,n-n1), (n-n1+2)/3, -1
               L2 = choose(n2)
               current = merge(current+1,1,n2 == n1)
               w2 = w1*current
               do n3 = min(n2,n-n1-n2), (n-n1-n2+1)/2, -1
                  L3 = choose(n3)
                  current = merge(current+1,1,n3 == n2)
                  w3 = w2*current
                  n4 = n-n1-n2-n3
                  L4 = choose(n4)
                  current = merge(current+1,1,n4 == n3)
                  w4 = w3*current
                  term = 24/w4*L1*L2*L3*L4
                  write(*,'(*(g0))') n1,'&',n2,'&',n3,'&', &
                     n4,'&',24/w4,'&',L1,'&',L2,'&',L3,'&', &
                     L4,'&',term,'\\'
                  nfree = nfree+term
               end do
            end do
         end do
         write(*,'(*(g0))') '\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for ',n,' cards:}}&',nfree
         write(*,'(a)') '\end{array}$$'
      end function nfree
      subroutine init_params
         integer i
         integer(INT64) j
         integer(INT64) fact(0:13)
         fact = [(product([(j,j=1,i)]),i=0,13)]
         choose = [(fact(13)/fact(i)/fact(13-i),i=0,13)]
      end subroutine init_params
end module FlushFun

program flush2
   use FlushFun
   implicit none
   integer(INT64) free
   integer n
   call init_params
   do n = 4,17
      free = nfree(n)
   end do
end program flush2
```

And here are the tables in prints out:
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&0&0&0&4&715&1&1&1&2860\\
3&1&0&0&12&286&13&1&1&44616\\
2&2&0&0&6&78&78&1&1&36504\\
2&1&1&0&12&78&13&13&1&158184\\
1&1&1&1&1&13&13&13&13&28561\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 4 cards:}}&270725
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&1&0&0&12&715&13&1&1&111540\\
3&2&0&0&12&286&78&1&1&267696\\
3&1&1&0&12&286&13&13&1&580008\\
2&2&1&0&12&78&78&13&1&949104\\
2&1&1&1&4&78&13&13&13&685464\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 5 cards:}}&2593812
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&2&0&0&12&715&78&1&1&669240\\
4&1&1&0&12&715&13&13&1&1450020\\
3&3&0&0&6&286&286&1&1&490776\\
3&2&1&0&24&286&78&13&1&6960096\\
3&1&1&1&4&286&13&13&13&2513368\\
2&2&2&0&4&78&78&78&1&1898208\\
2&2&1&1&6&78&78&13&13&6169176\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 6 cards:}}&20150884
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&3&0&0&12&715&286&1&1&2453880\\
4&2&1&0&24&715&78&13&1&17400240\\
4&1&1&1&4&715&13&13&13&6283420\\
3&3&1&0&12&286&286&13&1&12760176\\
3&2&2&0&12&286&78&78&1&20880288\\
3&2&1&1&12&286&78&13&13&45240624\\
2&2&2&1&4&78&78&78&13&24676704\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 7 cards:}}&129695332
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&0&0&6&715&715&1&1&3067350\\
4&3&1&0&24&715&286&13&1&63800880\\
4&2&2&0&12&715&78&78&1&52200720\\
4&2&1&1&12&715&78&13&13&113101560\\
3&3&2&0&12&286&286&78&1&76561056\\
3&3&1&1&6&286&286&13&13&82941144\\
3&2&2&1&12&286&78&78&13&271443744\\
2&2&2&2&1&78&78&78&78&37015056\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 8 cards:}}&700131510
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&1&0&12&715&715&13&1&79751100\\
4&3&2&0&24&715&286&78&1&382805280\\
4&3&1&1&12&715&286&13&13&414705720\\
4&2&2&1&12&715&78&78&13&678609360\\
3&3&3&0&4&286&286&286&1&93574624\\
3&3&2&1&12&286&286&78&13&995293728\\
3&2&2&2&4&286&78&78&78&542887488\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 9 cards:}}&3187627300
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&2&0&12&715&715&78&1&478506600\\
4&4&1&1&6&715&715&13&13&518382150\\
4&3&3&0&12&715&286&286&1&701809680\\
4&3&2&1&24&715&286&78&13&4976468640\\
4&2&2&2&4&715&78&78&78&1357218720\\
3&3&3&1&4&286&286&286&13&1216470112\\
3&3&2&2&6&286&286&78&78&2985881184\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 10 cards:}}&12234737086
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&3&0&12&715&715&286&1&1754524200\\
4&4&2&1&12&715&715&78&13&6220585800\\
4&3&3&1&12&715&286&286&13&9123525840\\
4&3&2&2&12&715&286&78&78&14929405920\\
3&3&3&2&4&286&286&286&78&7298820672\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 11 cards:}}&39326862432
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&4&0&4&715&715&715&1&1462103500\\
4&4&3&1&12&715&715&286&13&22808814600\\
4&4&2&2&6&715&715&78&78&18661757400\\
4&3&3&2&12&715&286&286&78&54741155040\\
3&3&3&3&1&286&286&286&286&6690585616\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 12 cards:}}&104364416156
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&4&1&4&715&715&715&13&19007345500\\
4&4&3&2&12&715&715&286&78&136852887600\\
4&3&3&3&4&715&286&286&286&66905856160\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 13 cards:}}&222766089260
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&4&2&4&715&715&715&78&114044073000\\
4&4&3&3&6&715&715&286&286&250896960600\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 14 cards:}}&364941033600
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&4&3&4&715&715&715&286&418161601000\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 15 cards:}}&418161601000
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
4&4&4&4&1&715&715&715&715&261351000625\\
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 16 cards:}}&261351000625
\end{array}$$
$$\begin{array}{rrrr|r|rrrr|r}
\rlap{\text{Number}}&&&&&\rlap{\text{Hands in Suit}}&&&&\\
\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Ways}&\clubsuit&\diamondsuit&\heartsuit&\spadesuit&\text{Total}\\
\hline
\hline&&&&&&&&\llap{\text{Hands for 17 cards:}}&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: I appreciate the help but would there be a way to do it mathematically and not through brute force? I'd like to be able to explain it through an equation.

Comment: Well, brute force is a discipline of mathematics in its own right and somehow I am tempted to say that quantity has a quality all its own. If you think about it, you are trying to find all the partitions of, say, $10$ into $4$ numbers each no larger than $4$, then for each partition there is a corresponding number of hands... The brute force approach above executed essentially instantly on my PC. I would be surprised if there is an elegant solution, but maybe you can bump your question on Monday when more potential correspondents are available and see if they come up with something.

Comment: This answer is not brute force. Brute force would be making $10363194502115$ iterations to try each possible $16$-card hand one at a time and counting how many were flushes. This answer actually uses combinatoric math to count many hands at a time, but the formulas are very messy. (And most of the fault for the messiness of the formulas is in the question itself, not in the program.)

Comment: @David K It was kind of brute force in that, for example, a partition that could be distributed among the suits in $12$ possible ways was given an iteration for each of the $12$ ways. Generating each partition only once saves enough computational effort that the whole project could be completed by hand, although the original program ran so quickly that it was clearly not worth the effort from a practical standpoint to perform all the extra programming to make life easier for the computer.

Comment: OK, if you like, we could call this program "a little brute-force-ish." Even my answer seems a _little_ brute-force-ish. I think it's in the nature of the problem that we tend to give up trying to be as clever as we can, because it seems we're going to end up crunching a lot of numbers no matter what. And I think that's a good decision.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is use a generating function.

Let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-card hands which do **not** include a 5-card flush, i.e., each suite has 0,1,2,3, or 4 cards in the hand.  Define the generating function 
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
Then
$$f(x) = \left[ 1 + \binom{13}{1} x + \binom{13}{2} x^2 + \binom{13}{3} x^3 + \binom{13}{4} x^4 \right]^4$$ 
which yields, on expansion (I used a computer algebra system)
$$f(x) = 1+52 x+1326 x^2+22100 x^3+270725 x^4+2593812 x^5+20150884 x^6+129695332
   x^7+700131510 x^8+3187627300 x^9+12234737086 x^{10}+39326862432
   x^{11}+104364416156 x^{12}+222766089260 x^{13}+364941033600
   x^{14}+418161601000 x^{15}+261351000625 x^{16}$$

The probability that an $n$-card hand does not include a 5-card flush is 
$$p_n = \frac{a_n}{\binom{52}{n}}$$
so, for example,
$$p_6 = \frac{20150884}{\binom{52}{6}} = 0.989801$$
and the probability a 6-card hand **does** include a 5-card flush is $1-p_6 = 0.010199$.

Answer (score -1):

A simple approach!
You draw say 10 cards.
The probability that any of these cards is a particular suite is 1/4. Conversely the prob that any card in not say a diamond is 3/4.
Then what is probability that 5 cards are the same suite is inverse that any 5 cards are Not the same suite. This is simply 3/4 ^ 5 = 23.7%. So prob of a simple 5 card flush from 10 cards is  76.3% which to a card player  feels about right!
Cheers

Comment: Have you noticed that the result should depend on the parameter $n$?